# Multisite redirecting wrong when without WWW

Tags: multisite, domain

Our Multisite WordPress installation has 3 subdomains:

```
    www.website.com
    www.website.com/en/
    www.website.com/es/
```

But when some URL without WWW is typed, the user is always redirected to `www.website.com`. For example:

```
    Typing:                         Leads to:
    website.com/                    www.website.com
    website.com/en/                 www.website.com
    website.com/es/                 www.website.com
    website.com/wp-admin/           www.website.com
    website.com/en/wp-admin/        www.website.com
    website.com/es/wp-admin/        www.website.com
    [...]                           [...]
```

We have tried:

- Forcing WWW with .htaccess
- Changing configuration on Domain Network Dashboard

But none of that solved the problem.

We have not tried any plugin yet because we don't know exactly what our problem is.

What can be happening?

Comment: Are you using the WPML Plugin for the languages? Or are these Sites of the Network based on folders, not subdomains?

Comment: No, I'm not using any plugin. I just activated multisite feature, created 2 more sites on the network, based on folders, and we are creating each site separately. I believe it is based on folders because we access them following a folder structure (website.com/en, website.com/es) only.